# Why I get "This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type float" error?

Tags: ocaml

I need to find the square roots of a quadratic equation: ax^2+bx+c=0.

```
let h a b c = 
  if (b*b-4*a*c) < 0 then begin 
    print_string "There are no real solutions" 
  end
  else if (b*b-4*a*c) = 0 then begin
    print_string "The equation has 1 solution x_1=";
    print_int ((-b)/(2*a));
  end
  else begin
    float_of_int a;
    float_of_int b;
    float_of_int c;
    print_float (((-.b)+.sqrt(b*.b-.4.*.a*.c))/.(2.*.a)); 
    print_float (((-.b)-.sqrt(b*.b-.4.*.a*.c))/.(2.*.a))
  end;;
```

Why this code gives me syntax error here saying that "This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type float":

```
begin
  float_of_int a;
  float_of_int b;
  float_of_int c;
  print_float (((-.b)+.sqrt(b*.b-.4.*.a*.c))/.(2.*.a)); 
  print_float (((-.b)-.sqrt(b*.b-.4.*.a*.c))/.(2.*.a))
end;;
```

Also is there any other easier way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I edited your question because it was unreadable, try to format it like this in the future ;-)

For the answer, here's your problem : OCaml is a functional language so when you write `float_of_int a` it doesn't change `a` (you should have had a warning saying that this expression returns something but you don't handle it). The type of `float_of_int` is `int -> float` so you give it an integer and it gives you back a float that you need to store in a variable.

What you should write is then :

```
begin
  let a = float_of_int a in
  let b = float_of_int b in
  let c = float_of_int c in
  print_float (((-.b)+.sqrt(b*.b-.4.*.a*.c))/.(2.*.a)); 
  print_float (((-.b)-.sqrt(b*.b-.4.*.a*.c))/.(2.*.a))
end;;
```

---

Side note : I don't know why you don't cast it as a float in the second branch since `-b/2a` is not necessarily an integer

---

And as another side note, since you use `b*b - 4*a*c` four times, put it in the variable in the beginning : `let delta = b*b - 4*a*c in ...`

Comment: Thanks for the help and for the side note :D. I will try to solve it and write back. But what does "in" mean after every "let"? Can I put ";" instead of "in"?

Comment: That's one of the things I hate with OCaml syntax. You have two kinds of `let` : the global one which is used to declare functions and variables (and other things) and the local one which is used to declare, well, local functions or variables (and other local things). When you declare local things you have to write `in` as in "let declare the variable a which is equal to 3 in the rest of this block". Yes, it's incoherent, I would prefer a `val` as global declaration but well, you don't have to chose, right? (I added another side note)

Comment: Oh I got it. So when I add a variable inside a block like inside a function I always need to write "in" after i declare it so it is like "let the variable in the function"??

Comment: Exactly. When you use let in a block you always need an in. ;-)

Comment: And also I know that if I have more expresions in an "if" lets say I need to separate them with ";". When you declare variables you do not need to use ";"?

Comment: I don't know who told you that. If you have instructions (which are expressions that return nothing -the unit type in OCaml), you don't have to store the result in a variable so you don't need to write a let in (but you could write `let () = print_int 1 in...`) so you write `print_int 1` and then you can see the problem, how to know when the instruction is over? That's why you end it with a `;` because you don't have `in` to mark the end.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for the tips!